# Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘Int’

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

```
howManyAboveAverage :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
howManyAboveAverage a b c
          | a && b && c >= m = 3
          | a && b >= m = 2
          | b && c >= m = 2
          | a && c >= m = 2
          | a || b || c >= m = 1
          | otherwise = 0
          where m = a + b + c
```

please why isnt this code running, I'm getting alot of errors i dont understand

Comment: Well the error is self-explaining. You write in your guard `a && b && ...`, but `a` is (according to your definition) an `Int`, and this is not a correct type of operand for `&&`.

Comment: try to explain what you need exactly in order to get the adequate answer

Comment: The `&&` doesn't distribute the `>= m` across to the other values. You have to be explicit `a >= m && b >= m && c >= m`. Also, don't forget to divide `m` by `3` to get the average instead of just the sum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You write in your code:

```
howManyAboveAverage :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
howManyAboveAverage a b c
          | a && b && c >= m = 3
          | a && b >= m = 2
          | b && c >= m = 2
          | a && c >= m = 2
          | a || b || c >= m = 1
          | otherwise = 0
          where m = a + b + c
```

I here put one case in boldface, but the error applies to all of them. You write as a condition `a && b && c >= m`. For Haskell this means that you write it like `a && b && (c >= m)`. Now `(&&)` is an operator that takes two booleans as operands, and calculates the logical and of these two. But the operands are no booleans. `c >= m` is a boolean, but `a` and `b` are no booleans.

So we have to write the condition on all operands like:

```
howManyAboveAverage :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
howManyAboveAverage a b c
          | a >= m && b >= m && c >= m = 3
          | a >= m && b >= m = 2
          | b >= m && c >= m = 2
          | a >= m && c >= m = 2
          | a >= m || b >= m || c >= m = 1
          | otherwise = 0
          where m = a + b + c
```

So now we have booleans, and the program will compile, but it is still semantically incorect. The average is the sum of the elements *divided by the number of elements*. Here the number of elements is 3, so we should divide it by three. Since dividing a number can lead to numerical errors, and would mean we have to work in the *floating point world*, it is safer to multiply the element with which we compare with three instead, so:

```
howManyAboveAverage :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
howManyAboveAverage a b c
          | a3 >= m  && b3 >= m  && c3 >= m = 3
          | a3 >= m  && b3 >= m = 2
          | b3 >= m  && c3 >= m = 2
          | a3 >= m  && c3 >= m = 2
          | a3 >= m  || b3 >= m  || c3 >= m = 1
          | otherwise = 0
          where m = a + b + c
                a3 = 3 * a
                b3 = 3 * b
                c3 = 3 * c
```

Now it works, but still it is not elegant: it requires five guards to check the number of conditions, and a total of twelve comparisons. This would thus be rather inefficient.

A better idea is probably to convert `True` to `1` and `False` to `0`, we can do this with the `bool` *catamorphism* function: [**`bool :: a -> a -> Bool -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Bool.html#v:bool). If we construct it like `bool 0 1` then we have a function that converts `False` to `0`, and `True` to `1`, we can then write it like:

```
import Data.Bool(bool)

howManyAboveAverage :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
howManyAboveAverage a b c = booltoint (3*a >= m)
                          + booltoint (3*b >= m)
                          + booltoint (3*c >= m)
          where m = a + b + c
                booltoint = bool 0 1
```

It can further be improved, but I leave this as an exercise.

Comment: Really like that `<pre><code>...</code></pre>` trick for using html to highlight code, totally stealing it.

Answer (score 3):

The `&&` operator has type `Bool -> Bool -> Bool`. This means that both operands have to be `Bool` and the result is also a `Bool`.

So for example, in the expression `a && b >= m`, the right operand (`b >= m`) is a `Bool`, but the left operand (`a`) is not - it's an `Int`.

So that's why you get an error: the left operand needs to be a `Bool`, too.

Comment: I understand now, Thanks